# stupeflix create simple tasks with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on a wordpress plugin using Stupeflix api, the old one with php.
I have to migrate it to the new one. But there's a real lack of explanation on stupeflix website, and no code example on how to do.

I created an account to test it. But it seems like I need to register a domain name. Ok. But what if I need to work localy ?

Then I use the task api. The JSON's a bit skinny : How would I pass my other params like my secret key ? How to keep it secret for example, if it's clearely readable in the source code ?

Thans for your spotlights :)

PS : I cannot create a stupeflix tag on stackoverflow. Such a shame, the stupeflix author told me to use that to get supports here...

Comment: As much as I'm sure the author of stupeflix would love to outsource his [non-free app](http://studio.stupeflix.com/en/pricing/) to SO to let others provide free support, [the "stupeflix" tag looks like it has never been used on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, even if it doesn't help me much.
This is the author's original mail to me : 
"Nous n'avons pas de community forum, mais vous pouvez poser vos questions directement sur stackoverflow avec un tag "stupeflix" pour que nous puissions les identifier."

Translation :
"We don't have community forum, but you can ask your questions directly on stackoverflow with the tag "stupeflix", in order, for us to identify 'em".

I would appreciate some help, indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

The new stupeflix API is a standard HTTP API with JSON bodies, and you can send requests to it with any librairy in any language. Every language has a decent HTTP requesting library, for example in Python I recommend python-requests or Jquery.ajax()

There's not code examples as such, but you have many [JSON examples here](https://developer.stupeflix.com/tasks/video.create/) though.

Most of the time, you only need to send POST requests to dragon.stupeflix.com/v2/create with a JSON body containing one or many tasks definitions :

```
{
  "task_name": "video.create",
  "definition": "<movie service=\"craftsman-1.0\">\n  <body>\n    <effect type=\"none\">\n      <video filename=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/stupeflix-assets/apiusecase/footage.mov\" speed=\"2.0\" audio=\"false\">\n        <filter type=\"colormap\" preset=\"bw\"/>\n      </video>\n    </effect>\n  </body>\n</movie>"
}
```

[Here is the documentation](https://stupeflix-tasks-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#method-v2_create). You will get a JSON response as such :

```
{
  "status": "executing",
  "result": {
    "duration": 10,
    "preview": "http://dragon.stupeflix.com/storage/flvstreamer/222/LY5XZIPILG6WKKIAGQAB4RLHBY/360p/preview.flv"
  },
  "key": "LY5XZIPILG6WKKIAGQAB4RLHBY",
  "progress": 10,
    "events": {
      "started": "2013-11-16T06:02:55.669278+00:00",
      "queued": "2013-11-16T06:02:55.667394+00:00"
  }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, what is meant by getenv("STUPEFLIX_HOST")